# Code Contracts Runtime Checking Exception

Tags: c#, code-contracts

We use Microsoft's code contracts in our codebase.

A project had `Contract.Requires` statements in it, without the build configuration that is released having "Perform Runtime Contract Checking" checkbox being ticked.

When the release build hits the `Contract.Requires` statement, an exception is generated.  This eventually trickles up and causes a `System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException` in the web service that uses the code contracts.

There was no indication anywhere in the exception** that this was a code contracts issue.

Is there any way to expose the fact that it's a code contract issue?

The issue was resolved by ticking the "Perform Runtime Contract Checking" checkbox for the release build configuration, but it would be good to ALSO have better diagnostic information available at runtime.

[image]

** Still working on digging into the inner exceptions.

Comment: Something seems fishy there.  When runtime checking is disabled, the rewriter is supposed to strip out contract statements entirely during the build.  Are you sure the Requires is actually where it was failing?  I'd be curious to see what the innermost exception is.  I know that some versions of the Code Contracts library would mess up debugging, highlighting the wrong lines and so on.  I don't know if that's still the case, but maybe that's what you're seeing?

Comment: Really?  Wow. Interesting information, thanks!  Still digging on the inner exception.

Comment: I presume the inner exception was telling you that you didn't enable the rewriter.

Comment: @Porges: Yes, though I haven't managed to grab the exception or update the question. That seems odd: Throw an exception because the rewriter is not enabled, but the rewriter doesn't need to be enabled if you don't want run-time checking.

Comment: @Porges: Thanks! That explains what I'm seeing.

Comment: @PeterK.: I think I'll move that comment to an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rewriter is always needed, even if you don't want runtime checking. The name of that option is misleading! If you want to turn off runtime checking, you need to enable that checkbox, but set the dropdown to "none".

If you don't have the rewriter enabled, the code will just call the actual methods in the Contracts class, which are really just dummy methods for the rewriter to access. If you actually call them, they just throw an exception.